# ActivityMonitor on Intent filter ACTION_SENDTO not hit

Tags: android, filter, android-intent, monitor, instrumentation

I am writing a JUnit test for an activity that launches the default mail client of the device. I want to validate that the "Send To" activity is started and then send a click event to the "Send" button.

I did set up an ActivityMonitor with an intent filter in order to get a reference on the "Send To" activity. I can see the send mail activity appear while running the test but unfortunately the monitor never gets hit.

Here is the unit test code that attempts to find the "Send To" activity:

```
// register activity monitor for the send mail activity
Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(filter, null, false);

// click on the "Send Feedback" button (use Robotium here)
solo.clickOnButton(0);

// wait for the send mail activity to start
Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5000);
assertNotNull(currentActivity);
```

And here is how the "Send To" activity is started in the application:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:address@mail.com");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);                                   
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Message Title");        
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
startActivity(i);
```

Is the intent filter incorrectly set? Or is it impossible to monitor activities that are not defined in the project?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem, I suppose that it is not possible to catch the intent at issue because there is no "real" activity started, in fact the list of the active activities after launching your intent is empty, but have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. I never solved that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with this as well and it turns out that the ActivityMonitor is not working, because Robotium's solo installs its own monitor. This monitor catches all intents, so your custom monitor is never called.

What I ended up doing was first removing the solo monitor, insert my own and and then re-add the solo monitor, so your monitor is matched first. Your code would then look something like this:

```
// register activity monitor for the send mail activity
Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
ActivityMonitor monitor = new ActivityMonitor(filter, null, false);
ActivityMonitor soloMonitor = solo.getActivityMonitor();

// Remove the solo monitor, so your monitor is first on the list.
instrumentation.removeMonitor(soloMonitor);
// add your own monitor.
instrumentation.addMonitor(monitor);
// Re-add the solo monitor
instrumentation.addMonitor(soloMonitor);

// click on the "Send Feedback" button (use Robotium here)
solo.clickOnButton(0);

// wait for the send mail activity to start
Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5000);
assertNotNull(currentActivity);
```

As a side note: when starting another activity (the mail application), you lose control of the testing environment, so it would be useful to make the monitor blocking (i.e `new ActivityMonitor(filter, null, true);`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my tests and this worked for me.

At this point your test is working fine, but your monitor doesn't know which data to expect, so your intent filter is not catching anything.

```
// register activity monitor for the send mail activity    
Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();    
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);


//Here you just need to say to your intent filter what exactly to look for 
filter.addDataType(CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE);



ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(filter, null, true);
// click on the "Send Feedback" button (use Robotium here)
solo.clickOnButton(0);    
// wait for the send mail activity to start
Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5000);
assertNotNull(currentActivity);
```

if you do this for sending sms, that line would be:

```
filter.addDataScheme(Constants.SCHEME_SMS);
```